# Unable to load overlay images on google map on relaunch activity - Android

Tags: android

I take an image from an activity which I place on the map as `ItemizedOverlay`. But the problem is when I relaunch the app, it does not show the overlay image. Please help

Comment: can you show some code...???

Comment: I can show the code. But it contains many classes which is not possible to show here. Could I show you some specific method.

Comment: just show that code which show overlays...

Answer (score 0):

in `onResume` you can try to create the list overlay again and set to the map.

This is kinda workaround, actual ans will depend on the way you implemented till now.